# how to write a program that using lists for calculating GPA of students in python

Tags: python, list

I have to write a program in python that user inputs 3 majors and then he inputs students for each major with their classes and their scores for each class and then my program should calculate each student's GPA and then prints the best and worst student according to their GPA.

I was thinking to a program that is has 3 major lists and each list has another list inside of it for students and each student list has another two lists inside of it for classes and scores! But it seems impossible because for writing it I don't know user's inputs so I can not call the student name.
I mean if I had this list:

```
Math = [Jack[], Max[], Sarah[]]
```

I could easily use `Jack[]` but when I don't know users inputs so I can not write the program this way!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is late, but maybe you could work with dictionaries:

```
majors = {}

for i in range(3):
    major = input('Insert a major\n')
    majors[major] = {}

print("To terminate type 'end'\n")
for major in majors:
    student = ""
    while student != "end":
        student = input('Insert a student for major {}\n'.format(major))
        if student != "end":
            majors[major][student] = {}
            stud_class = ""
            while stud_class != "end":
                stud_class = input('Insert a class for student {}\n'.format(student))
                if stud_class != "end":
                    grade = input('Insert grade\n')
                    majors[major][student][stud_class] = grade

print(majors)
# Example throwing inside some random bunch of data, just so you can get the feeling
>> {'Math': {'Laura': {'IT': '10', 'English': '8'}, 'Marco': {'Spanish': '4'}}, 'English': {'Jen': {'IT': '9'}}, 'Spanish': {}}
```

Of course you'll have to add validation on user input because things could easily go wrong.

Also majors are fixed in number, but the students and classes for each students aren't. A simple solution to stop the input could be: when the user enters `"end"` you discard that input and pass to the next thing.

Hope this helps!